# Code doesn't execute function, despite no error messages, what did I do wrong? | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For some reason when I run this code it doesn't want to execute the function, I get no error messages or output. But the weird part is I've tested the first block of code before the `multiple_account_scan()` function and it does what I want it, the problem seems to be the second part, where it decides whether or not `default_list` is True or False. I honestly don't know what to do here as there are no error messages.

```
message_response = ['/V/M/itechexplore, techcrunch, technology', 'ndjakdjna', 'edouhadas', 'sduahjkdan']

for message in message_response:

    if '/V/M/' in message:
        pre_account_list = []
        multiple_account_scan_accounts = message.removeprefix("/V/M/")

        pre_account_list.append(multiple_account_scan_accounts)

        for message in pre_account_list:
            if "," in message:
                pre2_account_list = message.split(", ")

        default_mode = False

    if '/V/M/R/' in message:
        default_mode = True


def multiple_account_scan():
    print('my brain is high IQ')


try:
    if default_mode is True or False:
        multiple_account_scan()
except:
    print('No option inputted')
```

Comment: can you correct the identation and format ?

Comment: Edit the question to show what happens (properly formatted output) and what should happen.

Comment: `if default_mode is True or False:` what's the point of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if default_mode is True or False` isn't right, that means

- either `default_mode is True`
- either `False` which is always `False`

It's equivalent to `if default_mode is True`

---

Then if no matter it would be True or False you go into the if, that means you always go, or the purpose if to use the fact that the variable won't defined and you'll go in the `except`

Do

```
if default_mode in [True, False]:
    multiple_account_scan()
# or
if default_mode is True or default_mode is False:
    multiple_account_scan()
```